# WhiteSpace When Resizing Webpage

Tags: html, css

I've been working on creating a resume but have an issue with white space in the "Work History" section. Once you start to collapse the webpage the unordered lists run off the page and create unwanted white space along the right side of the page. I've tried quite a few things as well as searching for answers but I'm still at a loss to fix this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="leftcolumn">
    <p><b>Assurant Inc, Remote Technical Support</b></p>
  <p>April 2017 - Present</p>
</div>
<div id="rightcolumn">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Remote support of mobile devices for customers of T-Mobile, US Cellular, and Comcast.</li>
        <li>Technical support via Intercom, phone call, and email.</li>
        <li>Mobile application support for iOS and Android.</li>
        <li>Training customers on utilization of "Pocket Geek," company application.</li>
        <li>Document resolutions in Microsoft Dynamics.</li>
        <li>Add articles to knowledge base in Microsoft Dynamics.</li>
        <li>Supporting customers with in home Smart Devices such as August Smart Lock, Philips Hue, LIFX, Amazon Echo, Google Home, as well as others.</li>
      </ul>
     <hr>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/bgongre/full/EXKXye/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, to be honest, but could it have something to do with the two `<hr>` elements on the right side of the list? They seem out of place.

Comment: do u have it hosted anywhere? because it looks like a problem with codepen. but still, I am sure. I investigated your code and found issue

Comment: The link to the codepen page is right above the text "Thanks in advance." I'll try to post it here if I can..https://codepen.io/bgongre/full/EXKXye/

Comment: No extra white spacing in your code. You only set fixed width to columns. If you want to cover at entire width. Try to change #rightcolumn{width:80%}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your css:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
#leftcolumn {
    width: 20%;
}
#rightcolumn {
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have one more question for you. Since that worked I messed with the #rightcolumn width and would like it to be about 80% so it doesn't look all squished while viewing full page. How can I set the left column to hop above the right column during collapse when it gets too small?

Comment: You'll get the best view if you use bootstrap, it would deal with all page view widths for you. Otherwise, there is min-width for you. You can add     `min-width: 200px;` to your #leftcolumn.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to id=wrapper the following property  "display: inline-block;"  but remember, you can´t repeat id so you will have to name this layer with a class